# Laravel 5.7: Phpunit error - call to a member function getBag() on a string

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.7

I'm testing saving data into the database. When missing required fields I throw an exception and then redirect from my controller:

```
try {
            $product = Product::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'description' => $request->description,
            ]);

            return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Record has been added');

        } catch(\Exception $e) {

            return redirect()->to('course/create')
                    ->withInput($request->input())
                    ->with('errors', 'Required Fields Not Submitted');
        }
```

I wanna test the redirect, whether the session has errors and whether the initial data passed is returned in order to populate the form, so in my unit test I have:

```
$response = $this->post("/courses/", $data);

$response->assertRedirect('/courses/create');
$response->assertSessionHasErrors();
//$response->assertSessionHasAll();
$response->assertHasOldInput();
```

but when hitting assertSessionHasErrors I'm getting:

> Error: Call to a member function getBag() on string

and when hitting assertHasOldInput I'm getting:

> BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::assertHasOldInput()

what seems to be the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
$response = $this->call('POST',  "/courses/", $data);

$response->assertRedirect('/courses/create');
$response->assertSessionHasErrors();
$response->assertHasOldInput();
```

Comment: You cannot do that I believe, the redirect comes from the response, so when changed to $this it'll say undefined method assertRedirect()

Comment: let's debug... Do a `dd($response)`... What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **call** method instead of **post**

Docs - [Calling Routes From Tests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing#calling-routes-from-tests)

Try this

```
$response = $this->call("POST", "/courses/", $data);
$response = $this->assertRedirect('/courses/create');
$response = $this->assertSessionHasErrors();
$response = $this->assertHasOldInput();
```

Comment: Nope, the errors are still present and they are the same as before